# Custom User Location Annotation Callout doesn't work

Tags: swift, mapkit

I want to change the standard annotation callout view for the user location annotation in Swift.

Therefore I created a custom XIB and a custom class. In the mapkit delegate I load the respective annotations. The custom annotations appear for every map annotation added as expected but not for the "current user location". Here the standard one is being displayed still. How do I need to change my code so the standard one will be exchanged to the one below?

[image]

```
 func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

        var identifier = ""

        if (annotation is MKUserLocation) {
            identifier = "userLocation"
            let annotationInfo:[String:AnyObject] = ["featureTypeId": GISFeatureType.AnnotationCurrentPosition.rawValue]

            if let userAnnotation = MapAnnotation(annotationInfo: annotationInfo) {
                userAnnotation.title = "Aktueller Standort"
                let annotationView = MapAnnotationView(annotation: userAnnotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
                annotationView.canShowCallout = true

                return annotationView
            }
        }

        // Annotation is not user location
        guard let annotation = annotation as? MapAnnotation, let featureTypeId = annotation.featureTypeId else {
            return nil
        }

        identifier = "MapAnnotation"
        let annotationView = MapAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)

        switch (featureTypeId) {
        case .AnnotationIncident:
            identifier = "MapAnnotationIncidentDetailView"
            let detailView = UIView.loadFromNibNamed(identifier) as! MapAnnotationIncidentDetailView
            detailView.incident = annotation.incident
            annotationView.detailCalloutAccessoryView = detailView

        case .AnnotationAED:
            identifier = "MapAnnotationAEDDetailView"
            let detailView = UIView.loadFromNibNamed(identifier) as! MapAnnotationAEDDetailView
            detailView.aed = annotation.aed
            annotationView.detailCalloutAccessoryView = detailView

        case .AnnotationCurrentPosition:
            identifier = "MapAnnotationCurrentDetailView"
            let detailView = UIView.loadFromNibNamed(identifier) as! MapAnnotationCurrentDetailView
            annotationView.detailCalloutAccessoryView = detailView

        default:
            return nil
        }


        annotationView.canShowCallout = true
        return annotationView
    }
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a technical description.

Comment: added more detail.